# google maps places auto complete api does not return plus code

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

i am using places auto complete api as below:

```
 let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

        //verify result
        if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
          return;
        }

console.log("formated address:", place.formatted_address)
console.log("plus cordinates:", place.plus_code)
```

I can see formatted_addresss is getting printed but plus_code is undefined. As per the docs
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult

I should see it.

The response from the object is

```
address_components: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
adr_address: "<span class=\"street-address\">12112 Anderson Mill Rd</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Austin</span>, <span class=\"region\">TX</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">78726</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">USA</span>"
formatted_address: "12112 Anderson Mill Rd, Austin, TX 78726, USA"
geometry: {location: _.Ee, viewport: _.Cf}
html_attributions: []
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png"
icon_background_color: "#7B9EB0"
icon_mask_base_uri: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet"
name: "12112 Anderson Mill Rd"
place_id: "ChIJU9d0CWEyW4YR-mTqmuuXqUY"
reference: "ChIJU9d0CWEyW4YR-mTqmuuXqUY"
types: ['premise']
url: "https://maps.google.com/?q=12112+Anderson+Mill+Rd,+Austin,+TX+78726,+USA&ftid=0x865b32610974d753:0x46a997eb9aea64fa"
utc_offset: (...)
utc_offset_minutes: -300
vicinity: "Austin"
```

Comment: It works for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v9cztkbh/).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, and/or provide an example autocomplete string that doesn't include the plus_code.  Also, FYI [plus_code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacePlusCode) is an object.

Comment: updated the response i am getting

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, preferably a working code snippet in the question itself.

Comment: That response doesn't include the plus code.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v9cztkbh/1/), it is [optional](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.plus_code), which means it doesn't **have** to be there.

Comment: ok if its optional then i cannot rely on it to be always returned by google.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.plus_code), "plus_code" is **optional**:

> **plus_code** ***optional***  
> Type:  PlacePlusCode optional
> Defines Open Location Codes or "plus codes" for the Place.

Which means it isn't guaranteed to be there.

You can write your code to handle the case when it is not there.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v9cztkbh/2/)

[image: screenshot w/ plus_code]

[image: screenshot w/o plus_code]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 30.307984,
      lng: -97.753401
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeControl: false,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
    console.log("bounds=" + map.getBounds().toUrlValue(6));
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
    console.log("zoom=" + map.getZoom());
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
    console.log("center=" + map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6));
  })
  const card = document.getElementById("pac-card");
  const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
  const biasInputElement = document.getElementById("use-location-bias");
  const strictBoundsInputElement = document.getElementById("use-strict-bounds");
  const options = {
    // fields: ["formatted_address", "geometry", "name", "plus_code"],
    strictBounds: false,
    types: ["establishment"],
  };

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(card);

  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
  // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
  // bounds option in the request.
  autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);

  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  const infowindowContent = document.getElementById("infowindow-content");

  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
  });

  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);

    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }
    console.log("place:" + JSON.stringify(place))
    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "name:" + place.name + "<br>" + place.formatted_address + "<br>";
    if (place.plus_code && place.plus_code.compound_code)
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += place.plus_code.compound_code;
    infowindowContent.children["place-name"].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children["place-address"].textContent =
      place.formatted_address;
    if (place.plus_code && place.plus_code.compound_code)
      infowindowContent.children["place-pluscode"].textContent = place.plus_code.compound_code;
    else
      infowindowContent.children["place-pluscode"].textContent = "";
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    const radioButton = document.getElementById(id);

    radioButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
      input.value = "";
    });
  }

  setupClickListener("changetype-all", []);
  setupClickListener("changetype-address", ["address"]);
  setupClickListener("changetype-establishment", ["establishment"]);
  setupClickListener("changetype-geocode", ["geocode"]);
  setupClickListener("changetype-cities", ["(cities)"]);
  setupClickListener("changetype-regions", ["(regions)"]);
  biasInputElement.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (biasInputElement.checked) {
      autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);
    } else {
      // User wants to turn off location bias, so three things need to happen:
      // 1. Unbind from map
      // 2. Reset the bounds to whole world
      // 3. Uncheck the strict bounds checkbox UI (which also disables strict bounds)
      autocomplete.unbind("bounds");
      autocomplete.setBounds({
        east: 180,
        west: -180,
        north: 90,
        south: -90
      });
      strictBoundsInputElement.checked = biasInputElement.checked;
    }

    input.value = "";
  });
  strictBoundsInputElement.addEventListener("change", () => {
    autocomplete.setOptions({
      strictBounds: strictBoundsInputElement.checked,
    });
    if (strictBoundsInputElement.checked) {
      biasInputElement.checked = strictBoundsInputElement.checked;
      autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);
    }

    input.value = "";
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding: 0;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
    <div>
      <div id="title">Autocomplete search</div>
      <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked" />
        <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment" />
        <label for="changetype-establishment">establishment</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address" />
        <label for="changetype-address">address</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode" />
        <label for="changetype-geocode">geocode</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-cities" />
        <label for="changetype-cities">(cities)</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-regions" />
        <label for="changetype-regions">(regions)</label>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
        <input type="checkbox" id="use-location-bias" value="" />
        <label for="use-location-bias">Bias to map viewport</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="" />
        <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict bounds</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pac-container">
      <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" value="12112 Anderson Mill Rd, Austin, Texas" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br />
    <span id="place-address"></span><br />
    <span id="place-pluscode"></span>
  </div>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code for this address 12112 Anderson Mill Rd shows the plus code but mine does not return.

Comment: Not for me (I don't get the plus code in the response).  You didn't provide a [mcve] in your question, so even if you updated your code, can't do more that guess what the issue is.

Comment: well i am seeing plus code in the UI or if i google this location on google maps. so not in my code but i see it exists.